# Getting infinite loop instead of expected controlled iteration

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, infinite-loop

When I run the below code, it's going into infinite loop.

My expectd output is to print `Hello` 2 times and exit. What is the issue here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < 2)
    {
      l1 :  i++;
        while (j < 3)
        {
            printf("Hello\n");
            goto l1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you never increase `j`, so that is not so surprising...

Comment: @SouravGhosh Wrong, `i` is incremented. It is just never checked because of `goto`.

Comment: @moktor Aaah, that's what I meant (see my answer)... Removed the wrong comment, though.

Comment: Also add return 0 before closing main().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `j` never changes value in your code.  This is problematic, because every time the loop runs and jumps to `L1`, it goes right back into looping. `(i < 2)` never gets checked, because it happens before the label `L1`.

Unless you are using this as an exercise to learn assembly-style programming, I would recommend avoiding using `goto`'s in C. It makes code harder to debug, and creates problems you may not notice right away, like this one.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is doing what it is supposed to do.

By saying `goto ll;`, you're essentially *skipping* the `while (i < 2)` check. using a `goto` does not transfer the program control to the loop. It takes the control to the first statement of the block under that label.

Instead, you can try using `break;` to get the expected result. `break;` will break out of the *inner* `while` loop and the program control will reach the outer `while` loop.

<kbd>[LIVE DEMO](http://rextester.com/KSDX29920)</kbd>

Also note, the recommended form of `main()` is `int main(void)`

---

<sup>[*Maybe I'm biased towards the removal of `goto`, so I did not notice, there is another possible solution, with `goto` also*]</sup>

Another approach, you can increment `j` after the label statement, outside the inner `while` loop. That way, after two `goto`s , `j` will become `3`, so, the inner `while` will be false, and then, the control will reach the other `while` and after one silent iteration, it will also become false, so the program will come out of the outer `while` and eventually terminate.

<kbd>[LIVE DEMO 2](http://rextester.com/AYLS60016)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `j++`

```
l1: i++;
    j++;    // add this to terminate it after 2 iterations
    while (j < 3)
    {
        ...
```

See http://ideone.com/ZbVo8y demo.

Comment: @SouravGhosh after coming back thrice to the label `l1` values will be `i = 3` and `j = 3`. So, message will be printed twice and both loops will terminate.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output exactly two times "Hello" with the minimum changes of the program then it is enough to add only two pluses (one operator) to the code.:)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < 2)
    {
      l1 :  i++;
        while (++j < 3)
        {
            printf("Hello\n");
            goto l1;
        }
    }
}
```

You can even make your program more complicated adding one more `goto` statement.:) For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    goto l2;
    while (i < 2)
    {
      l1 :  i++;
        while (++j < 3)
        {
            printf("Hello\n");
            l2:goto l1;
        }
    }
}
```

Nevertheless the program will ouput "Hello" two times as before.:)

By the way it is the way how programms are written in IBM.:) In IBM there are many great specialists on using goto statements.:)